# Where do I find the keys to unlock the locked doors I'm seeing in the various towers?

Tags: pandoras-tower

Where do I find the keys to unlock the various locked red doors in Pandora's Tower?

For that matter, does each key only unlock one door like they work in Zelda games?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can buy a key from Mavda after you finish the game.